# create insertion rule on view returning id

Tags: postgresql, view

I have a table private.products and a view public.products representing that table. And I want to create entries in private.products while inserting into view, it all works right, except that I also what to return the inserted id:

```
CREATE RULE insert_product 
AS ON INSERT TO public.products DO INSTEAD 
INSERT INTO private.products (name) VALUES (new.name) RETURNING products.id;
ERROR:  RETURNING list has too few entries
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please show the view and table definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your table and view structure, I created a test case for myself:

```
CREATE TABLE private_table (
    id serial, 
    col1 text
);


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public_view AS 
    SELECT id, col1 
      FROM private;


CREATE OR REPLACE RULE insert_private AS 
    ON INSERT TO public_view DO INSTEAD 
        INSERT INTO private_table (col1) 
        VALUES (new.col1) 
        RETURNING id, col1; -- apparently, this does not work with fewer columns 
                            -- or different ordering
```

So far, everything works fine, and there is an answer for your question: you have to add all columns of the **view** in the `RETURNING` clause of the rule.

What this does not achieve, though, is turning the `INSERT` into the view into something that returns the `id`:

```
INSERT INTO public_view (col1)
    VALUES ('blah');

INSERT 0 1
-- no id returned!
```

This absolutely makes sense, and can be avoided by adding the `RETURNING` clause to the actual `INSERT`, as usual:

```
INSERT INTO public_view (col1)
    VALUES ('blah2')
    RETURNING id;

 id 
────
  2
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
```